# How to split while keeping the empty line?

Tags: python, string, split

For example

```
'a b\n\n\nc'.split()
```

gives

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

while I want

```
['a','b','','','c']
```

Any ideas?

Comment: your question and expected output is totally different.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Would it be better if they pluralized "line" to "lines" in the title?  Otherwise, the question and expected output are pretty much exactly matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re.split`

```
re.split(r'[ \t]', s)
```

This would do splitting on white spaces or tabs.

Comment: I think this is the solution to my question. Thank you. Though I think the '\t' should be '\n'.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`str.splitlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines). Check [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) and you'll see that it splits on other newline-like characters too. If you want it to **only** split on `\n` then use [`str.split("\n")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

```
>>> "a\n\n\nb".splitlines()
['a', '', '', 'b']
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I did not put it quite clear. I need to split on whitespace while keeping the empty lines encountered somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Use - `.split('\n')`

Example -

```
>>> 'a\n\n\nb'.split('\n')
['a', '', '', 'b']
```

`split()` splits by all whitespaces, hence you do not get the lines inbwetween, instead you can send in `\n` as the parameter to split to tell it to split at each `\n` .

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, this works. Only that I still want to split by space while keep the empty lines.

Answer (score 0):

Use str.splitlines():

```
>>> 'a\n\n\nb'.splitlines()
['a', '', '', 'b']
```